# Redux Toolkit RTK Calling endpoint from within another using onQueryStarted

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I have 2 redux endpoint, getSimulatedPendingOrder and simulatePendingOrder

Does anyone have an example of using onQueryStarted: in getSimulatePendingOrder to call simulatePendingOrder using the same props ( inputParameters: { pendingOrderNumber } )

The error message on "simulatePendingOrder" in VSCODE is

```
Argument of type '"simulatePendingOrder"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryKeys<{ getPendingOrder: QueryDefinition<GetPendingOrderProps, BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, "Partners" | ... 56 more ... | "Incoterms", PendingOrder, "api">
```

.

```
            getSimulatedPendingOrder: builder.query<
                Cart.GetSimulatedPendingOrderFunction.ReturnType,
                Cart.GetSimulatedPendingOrderProps
            >({
                query: ({ inputParameters: { pendingOrderNumber } }) => ({
                    url: `${path}PendingOrders('${pendingOrderNumber}')?$expand=Messages,Items/Messages,Items/GroupProperties,SimulatedItems,Partners,SimulatedSubtotals,Texts&$format=json`,
                    method: "GET",
                    credentials: "same-origin",
                    headers: headers({})
                }),
            onQueryStarted: async ({ inputParameters: { pendingOrderNumber } }, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) => {
                const Result1 = dispatch(
                    cartApi.util.updateQueryData(
                        "simulatePendingOrder",
                        {
                            inputParameters: { pendingOrderNumber }
                        },
                        (draft) => {}
                    )
                );
                try {
                    await queryFulfilled;
                } catch (e) {
                    Result1.undo();
                }
            },
                serializeQueryArgs: ({ queryArgs: { inputParameters } }) => inputParameters,
                transformResponse: (response) => {
                    const cleanedBody = cleanSAPResponseBody(response as Record<string, unknown>) as PendingOrderExternal;
                    const pendingOrder = convertSimulatedOrder(cleanedBody);
                    return pendingOrder;
                },
                providesTags: (result) => [{ type: "PendingOrder", id: result?.pendingOrderNumber }]
            }),
            simulatePendingOrder: builder.mutation<void, { pendingOrderNumber: string }>({
                query: ({ pendingOrderNumber }) => ({
                    url: `${path}PendingOrders('${pendingOrderNumber}')/SimulatedItems?$format=json`,
                    method: "GET",
                    credentials: "same-origin",
                    headers: headers({})
                }),
                invalidatesTags: (_result, _error, props) => [
                    "PendingOrders",
                    { type: "PendingOrder", id: props.pendingOrderNumber }
                ]
            }),
```